# How to release mouse capture in VirtualBox?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, mouse, virtualbox

[image]

I'm on my MacbookPro and using TeamViewer for remote access to my 2k3 Server. On this server I installed VirtualBox to create a virtual machine. But now I stuck at this screen and no more can use my mouse.

How can I release the mouse capture?

Comment: You may want to consider using Remote Desktop to connect.

Answer (score 18):

You need to press "host key" which is written in right bottom corner of  VirtualBox window.

Looking at your screenshot its <kbd>**Right Ctrl**</kbd>.

Its not default Mac <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> because you are running VirtualBox on Windows host, which you are accessing using TeamViewer.

See virtualBox manual: [link](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#keyb_mouse_normal)

Comment: Note: That's the "Ctrl" key on the right-side of your keyboard. (Not "Ctrl" + "right arrow" keys, as I was trying.)

Answer (score 10):

Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd> at the same time to release the mouse from the VirtualBox window.

Comment: I tried it several times but had no luck. I found a solution for my problem: quit Teamviewer then login again , and I had my cursor back.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Delete</kbd> worked for me

[image]

Comment: It's ok to have a couple answers - especially if you add a screen shot showing how to execute this - not everyone knows where the delete key is on the Mac or knows you have to use a menu item or other software keyboard.

Comment: You've found a trick, the right way for windows is pressing **RightCtrl+RightAlt**

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2021: You must HOLD the RIGHT CTRL KEY while moving the mouse to escape the Virtual Machine.

If you look closely at the image below it shows the hotkey that needs to keep on pressing to escape from the virtual machine.

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks for this. Although it said Right Ctrl, it was the left one that works..

Answer (score 0):

You could also try triggering Sticky Keys (Press Shift repeatedly) that will pop you back to windows control. click no on the Sticky keys popup before you click back into virtual box (You can't trigger sticky keys if the pop up is open).

Answer (score 0):

You also use <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Del</kbd> per Teamviewer Panel.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue while I installed virtualbox for the first time.

To switch between host and the VB press "right ctrl" on your keyboard.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Already Virtualbox gives you the guide at the bootom right of the window:
[image]

for me, as you can see in the picture, i have to use the Command button (<kbd>⌘</kbd>) LEFT one.